# Qt for Embedded Linux: Hide cursor on startup

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, mouse-cursor

I'm developing a Qt application on a linux embedded system.
The system has got a touchscreen, but also an OTG USB port, and it must be usable with a mouse.

So my problem is, when the application starts, it shows a mouse cursor in the middle of the screen, and then it disapears when my main windows paint event occurs.

When the application has started, I can hide/show the cursor if a mouse is plugged in, that works great, but I always have the cursor during the startup.

I tried:
    QWSServer::setCursorVisible(false);

or:
    qApp->setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::BlankCursor));

and the result is the same as described above.

The only way I found to hide the cursor during startup was compiling Qt without the Cursor, but then I can't have a cursor when the mouse is plugged in (that's logic...).

So if you have an idea, I would be happy to read it :-)

Thanks,
Sylvain

EDIT:
Okey so that's the QWS Server that shows the cursor on startup, I found that in qt/src/gui/embedded/qwscursor_qws.cpp:

```
void QWSServerPrivate::initializeCursor()
{
    Q_Q(QWSServer);
// setup system cursors
#ifndef QT_NO_QWS_CURSOR
//    qt_screen->initCursor(sharedram + ramlen,true);

// default cursor
    cursor = 0;
    setCursor(QWSCursor::systemCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
#endif
    q->sendMouseEvent(QPoint(swidth/2, sheight/2), 0);
}
```

Now if I comment the "setCursor" instruction, that solves the problem, but that's kind of ugly to edit Qt source code to do that, so if you've got a better solution...

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to call ``qApp->setOverrideCursor()`` already in your main.cpp file before calling ``qApp->exec()``? This way you shouldn't see the cursor on startup.

Comment: That's what I did, but the cursor appears just after the call to "app = new QApplication(qtArgc, qtArgv);". I think it appears when the QWS Server starts.

Answer (score 6):

This does not work with *Qt5*; but from the question this seems to be *Qt4* with **QWS**.  The code sequence,

```
QWSServer *server = QWSServer::instance();
if(server) {
    server->setCursorVisible(false);
}
```

will work with *Qt4.x* using **QWS**.  An important point to note is that only the *server* may do this.  Ie, the program invoked with `-qws`.  If you run multiple applications, the clients will not be able to disable the cursor.

This should be done *after* the **QApplication** is constructed, but before the first *show()* or *showFullScreen()*.  You probably try to do this before the **QApplication** is constructed.

**Edit:** As you seem to mean when the application initially displays,

Add `#define QT_NO_QWS_CURSOR 1` to a *MyQconfig* file and pass it to `./configure` with the `-qconfig MyQconfig` option.  Or you can use the graphic tool `qconfig` to customize Qt.  `qconfig` is found in the tools directory.  A list of items is found in *src/corelib/global/qfeatures.txt*.  See [Fine tuning Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/fine-tuning-features.html) for more.

Comment: Yes I'm using Qt 4.8.4 with QWS.
I tried that in my main.cpp:
`app = new QApplication(qtArgc, qtArgv);

    QWSServer::setCursorVisible(false);

    windows = new MainWindows();
    windows->show();

    return app->exec();`
and it doesn't work, because the cursor is displayed by the QWSServer when the application is created, so that's before it came back from "new QApplication", so the cursor is displayed, and then disapears when the main windows is displayed.

Comment: I updated my answer with an edit assuming you never want the cursor.  If you want to not display the cursor initially, but then display it after some time, then the only choice is to modify the source.

Comment: Another possibility is to completely blank the screen until your application is running.  There are files in */sys/class/graphics* that can blank the display until the application is active.  **QWS** may automatically un-blank the display and you will see the cursor anyways; I haven't tested this.  For our system, we never want the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <QScreenCursor>
QScreenCursor *cursor = new QScreenCursor;
cursor->initSoftwareCursor();
cursor->hide();
```